# Detect if Application is launched by clicking app icon or by push notification (when app is force killed by user)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification

Testing in iOS 13, I still find difficulty on detecting whether the app is launch from app icon or from push notification.

I know we can check whether a notification key is existed in the launch options by following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
         // Launched from push notification
         NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    }
}
```

The problem is I found the "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey" is even presented when I launch the app by clicking the app icon with a pending notification present in the notification panel (The app is force killed). Only when I clear the notification in the panel, then launch the app by app icon, the "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey" is not there.

In this case, whether I launch from app icon or notification, the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey is still three, so I can't distinguish whether I should redirect app to the push content or launch as normal flow.

I heard some peoples said "didReceiveRemoteNotification" will be called after "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" if it's launched from notification, however, in my case, it doesn't, in both case, only "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" is called.

Anyone having the same issue in iOS 13 when the app is killed? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: More information:
1) kill app -> receive push -> open app by app icon -> UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey is there   

2) receive push -> kill app -> open app by app icon -> UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey is not there

Answer (score -2):

Just add below check

```
if (notification != nil) {
    // do your action
}
```

Also to check data, add alertview where you will print notification data.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" 
                                                    message:notification 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

**If notification is nil, means app is not opened by push. May be its opened when click on Open button on App store when you install new app.**

Comment: Thanks for help. But my problem is the notification Dictionary is existed even I launch the app by clicking the app icon (app is force closed, with notification in the notification panel). Any idea? Is this intended?

Comment: @MichaelChiu : In this case, for sure notification will be nil. It will not have data if you click on app icon directly.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Like @MichaelChiu describes, I can confirm that I observe the launchOptions dictionary in some cases is containing key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey and the push information value. I was not able to recognize a rule, nor did I find a hint in the official docs. However, I noticed that it also seem to matter _when_ you click on the app icon. If you opened a random (different) app or two in the meantime, it's less likely to contain the remote dict in the launch option. Also, if you wait _some_ time, chances rise that the launch option dict is nil.